# Форма для отправки с Light Box

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript, lightbox

Добра!

Нужно сделать форму для отправки, которая будет отображаться с лайтбоксом. Т.е., нажав на кнопку, выплывает лайтбокс с формой для заполнения.

Пример: http://akmetron.ru/ (заказ звонка).

Comment: А сами не хотите попробовать? Тут помогают решать трудности, а не делают за вас какие-либо вещи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте fancybox ( http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ ). Его можно открывать с произвольнми контентом, что-то вроде такого:

```
<div class="js-callback" style="display:none;">
    <form>
          <input />
    </form>
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
$.fancybox({
    content: $('.js-callback').html();
});
```